# Commenting out C++ code, visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am testing a C++ source and I want to comment out some part of the code. There is a shortcut in Visual Studio: <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> for commenting and <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> for uncommenting the code. I can successfully comment out the code but uncommenting it will not be an "undo". It always removes some characters from the existed comment lines. Here is an example:

```
/*function 1 */
int func1()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I want to comment out this code, I can apply <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> after selecting the code. And it becomes like this:

```
///*function 1 */
//int func1()
//{
//    return 0;
//}
```

If I want to un-comment the code, I should apply <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> after selecting it all. It becomes:

```
*function 1 */
int func1()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It removes an additional `'/'` and the old comment becomes corrupted. Is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how about doing the obvious and removing your old style comment and replace it with //

Comment: Actually, it is not my code. I am trying to port an application to windows. It will be very time consuming.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple lines of comments? search and replace will not work for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use

```
#if 0
{code here, lots of it even nested /* */ }
#endif
```